# Redirect from template to parent page - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, redirect

I got a template that i use like a block in his parent page, and i would like to redirect this template.

Could you tell me how can i redirect my page who got a template name to his parent page ?

I don't know how i can detect the template in my hook ...

i would like to do something like that :

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpnc_redirect_single' );
function wpnc_redirect_single() {
    $queried_post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
    if ( is_single() && 'reference' ==  $queried_post_type ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url(), 301 );
        exit;
    }
}
```

But here it's for a custom type

Thanks

Comment: That was stupid sorry ... here the soluce : 
    if (is_page_template("templates/template-pdf.php")){wp_redirect( home_url(), 301 );
        exit;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (is_page_template("templates/template-pdf.php")){
wp_redirect( home_url(), 301 );
 exit;
 }
```

Like that